# How to solve conflicts from gitlab?

Tags: git

I want to know how to resolve conflicts coming from github ? here is what I do

1. I switch to the **master branch** and I **git pull**
2. I switch back to my branch and I **git rebase master**
3. I resolve the conflicts and I **git add .** and I continue with **git rebase --continue**.

and i have a lot of conflicts on my own work how is it possible ?

Comment: after "conflict resolution" you have to commit.. !(?) (not "only add")

Comment: yes of course i commit and push

Comment: after you (resolved conflicts, committed &) push (<your_branch>), "your work" should be exact as the remote(as local) <your_branch>

Answer (score 1):

When you're resolving conflicts by the `rebase` command it is totally normal to see more than one time conflicts. the reason is in `rebase` command your branch is coming up commit by commit and is comparing your branch by all the commits to the top. so it is possible to have conflicts from once to the count of commits your branch is old from the target branch (in your example `master`).

You should fix the conflict, add and continue till all conflicts have been resolved.

Are you searching for another way to fix all conflicts once? sure there is. you could pull `master` on your branch.